# What does an italic "a" immediately before a year stand for?

Tags: orthography, citation

Some citations in the *OED* have an italic *a* before the year to indicate the year is uncertain, for example:

> *a*​1556   N. Udall *Ralph Roister Doister* (?1566) iii. iv. sig. E.iijv,   By gosse and for thy sake I defye hir in deede.

What does the *a* stand for in *a*​1556? In this case, the book was believed to have been published in 1556, or shortly thereafter, but not known for sure.

I don't think it's "about" because it's italic so possibly Latin, and italic *c* is also used for *circa* in other citations ("*c*​1315").

Comment: In this case, I think the book is believed to have been published around 1566, but was written and performed [several years before](http://home.vicnet.net.au/~bard/Ralph_Roister_Doister.html) publication. My guess would be that the _a_ means that it was written probably before, but no later than, 1556.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the OED's homepage, there's a Helpful resources section, with some links, including one to abbreviations, and another to a symbol key:

[image]

Either of those two links reveals:

[image]

I believe that, loosely translated, it means *sometime before*, when the precise date is unknown.

Answer (score 2):

According to [their public portion of the site](http://www.oed.com/public/abbreviations) an *a* before a date means "ante." So whereas *c* means something happened around a date, *a* means it happened before that date. In your specific instance, the use of gosse occurred before 1556 according to the quote entry.